# How to draw a \mapsto in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

Does anyone know how to draw a line which looks like `\mapsto` by using `\draw[...]...` in TikZ?

Comment: -1: Doesn't show any effort. I don't know any TikZ, but I don't think this should be too hard. (If something about it were hard, the specific problem could've been articulated.) We don't want "please do this for me" questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This uses the solution from [How to make an arrow bigger and change its color in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-make-an-arrow-bigger-and-change-its-color-in-tikz/27287#27287) to adjust the size of the arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\[a \mapsto b\]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red, |->, decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=1.7,red]{>}}},
    postaction={decorate},
    shorten >=0.4pt
] (0,0) node [black,left] {$a$} -- (0.4,0) node [black,right] {$b$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]