# Setting fill color for TikZ arrow tips only (and not the path itself)

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

For many TikZ diagrams, I’d like to draw colored (often gray) arrows.  I prefer the `latex`-style arrow tips (from the arrows library).  These are filled by using the default background fill color.  My problem is that complex paths cannot have a `fill=…` key because that would mean “fill the path (and the arrow tip)” rather than “fill the arrow tip” as in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, ->]
  % okay: all black
  \draw[] (2,0) to[bend left] ++(right:1cm); 

  % not okay: gray line, black tip
  \draw[draw=black!50] (3,0) to[bend left] ++(right:1cm); 

  % not okay: gray line, gray tip, path filled
  \draw[draw=black!50, fill=black!50] (4,0) to[bend left] ++(right:1cm); 

  % okay, but complicated: gray line, gray tip, path not filled
  \begin{scope}[fill=black!50]
    \draw[draw=black!50] (5,0) to[bend left] ++(right:1cm);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

The last arrow actually achieves the correct result – i. e., gray arrow, gray arrow tip, no background fill for path – but it is a bit cumbersome to use a scope for every colored arrow that I'm drawing.  So my question: Is there an easier way of influencing the arrow tip fill color?

BTW, I’m aware of the solution using the marking library in [How to make an arrow bigger and change its color in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-make-an-arrow-bigger-and-change-its-color-in-tikz), but I was hoping for a more elegant solution because using markings feels not very “natural” compared to using lines and arrow tips in TikZ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do only

```
  \draw[black!50] (5,0) to[bend left] ++(right:1cm);
```

Comment: Works for me, thanks.  I didn’t think of just leaving out the `fill` or `draw` key.

Comment: This is very useful, I had been looking for that for ages !

Comment: I feel stupid but I don't get this. How is this different from `\draw[draw=black!50] (3,0) to[bend left] ++(right:1cm);` in the OP's example? I just get a gray arrow with a black tip if I leave out the fill.