# Filling the arrow tip and not the path using two different colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, arrows, paths

I have a small problem with some arrows but I can't seem to find a solution. Please note that this question is different from [Setting fill color for TikZ arrow tips only (and not the path itself)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47976/setting-fill-color-for-tikz-arrow-tips-only-and-not-the-path-itself), since there the OP meant to make the whole arrow of one color.

If I wanted the arrow tip to be black and the arrow path to be colored, I'd simply say  `draw=black` but I need the opposite, a black path with a colored tip.

So this is what I get:

> [image]

And this is my code:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,decorations,shapes,shapes.multipart,positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

    \definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,127,255}

    \tikzset{
    opera/.style={fill=white, inner sep=0pt, right=3mm, text width= 5cm,font=\footnotesize},
    tear/.style={draw=black, fill=blue, -*},.
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[tear] (12, 5) -- (12,4) -- (10,3) -- (10,2) node[opera] at (10,2){Not the path!};

   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've tried removing as much as possible to make the code minimal so don't worry if you see unused packages or libraries.

I've thought as a possible solution to add an option like `>=stealth` but trying to set the color using the `o` or `*` arrow tips. None worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the following answer is based on `markings` and `postaction`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,decorations.markings,shapes,shapes.multipart,positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}

    \definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0,127,255}

    \tikzset{
    opera/.style={fill=white, inner sep=0pt, right=3mm, text width= 5cm,font=\footnotesize},
    tear/.style={draw=black,-, 
    decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[draw=black,fill=blue]{*}}},
    postaction=decorate},.
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[tear] (12, 5) -- (12,4) -- (10,3) -- (10,2);

   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces:
[image]

I removed the arrow head from your `tear` style and added `decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[draw=black,fill=blue]{*}}}` and `postaction=decorate`. In this way the arrowhead is drawn as a decoration at the end of your segment, without filling the path. You also need to load the decoration as a `postaction` with `postaction=decorate`, so that only the arrow head is overwritten and not the entire line.

---

**Edit:** The previous approach is now (with the releasing of PGF 3.0.0) obsolete:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,127,255}

    \tikzset{
        opera/.style={
            fill=white,
            inner sep=0pt,
            right=3mm,
            text width= 5cm,
            font=\footnotesize
        },
        tear/.style={
            -{Circle[fill=myblue]}      %new code, requires arrows.meta and at least PGF 3.0.0
        },
     }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[tear] (12, 5) -- (12,4) -- (10,3) -- (10,2) node[opera] {Not the path!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you're welcome, I actually discovered some cool stuff about markings while answering :)

Comment: Ahah that's great!