# Big wide arrows, how to?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I saw someone use this scripts to generate big arrows, but it seems quite tricky to me. And I also hope the arrow is not filled. Any good ideas?

```
\draw[
    -triangle 45,
    line width=1.0mm,
    postaction={draw, line width=0.25cm, shorten >=0.8cm, -}
] (2,-2) -- (2.5,-2);
```

Something like

```
------\
------/
```

Comment: Does [How to make an arrow bigger and change its color in TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-make-an-arrow-bigger-and-change-its-color-in-tikz) solve this issue?

Comment: No, I've seen that post before.

Comment: @PeterGrill and this: [Is it possible to change the size of an arrowhead in TikZ/PGF?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5461)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code first draws a relatively short line of 0.5 mm length with a ridiculous big line width of 1.0 mm which looks like

[image]

(The line width is used to a part in the calculation of the arrow tip size. This is an often used trick to get big arrow tips.)

The actual line lies under the arrow tip that is so big that it totally hides the line, with an `opacity=.5` setting we can see it (remember that the arrow itself contains of a line and a filled area, the filled area and the line create a darker triangle).

[image]

When this is done the same path is used again (`postaction`), but with different settings:

- a line width of 2.5 mm instead of 1 mm,
- no arrow (`-`), and
- the `>` part (in this case the end lies at `(2.5,-2)` is shorten by the amount of 8 mm.

The `draw` mode is used in the “normal action” because it is explicitly used with `\draw` but the `postaction` does not inherit this setting, but only the path itself.

This creates

[image]

The actual addition line due to `postaction` can be best seen if we draw it in another color (or use again `opacity`); with `draw=green` we see that it acutally overlaps the arrow:

[image]

Observe what happens if I remove the `shorten >` option (or set it to `0pt`):

[image]

Now, the actual end is at the tip of the arrow and with `shorten >=0.8cm` it is set 8 mm to the left. But as our line is only 5 mm long we actually get a reversed line of –3 mm length. The `postaction` does not know about our arrow anymore and can’t shorten the line as it does normally automatically.

Weird! This is probably not the most sufficient way to draw a big arrow. For these kinds of arrows we could have used the `single arrow` shape of the `shapes.arrows` library.

Your update implies (huh!) a totally different approach:

```
\tikz\draw[line width=1mm,-implies,double, double distance=1mm] (0,0) -- (1,0);
```

which produces

[image]

The `double distance` describes the distance between the doubled lines that are drawn with the usual line width (default: `thin` = `.4pt`, here `1mm`).

What actually happens:

- a line with the line width of `2 * 'line width' + 'inner distance'` is drawn
- a line with the line width of `inner distance` is drawn over it
- (and the arrow actually shortens the line too but that's a totally different chapter, see above)

We can add `opacity=.5` to highlight that again:

[image]

### Code

Neither the arrow tip nor a post action updates the bounding box, which is the reason I had to use a relatively thick border of `6pt`. This usually creates no problems in normal TikZ pictures.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={opacity=.5}}
\begin{document}
\tikz\draw[
    -triangle 45,
    line width=1.0mm,
    postaction={draw=green, line width=0.25cm, shorten >=0.0cm, -}
] (2,-2) -- (2.5,-2);
\tikz\draw[line width=1mm,-implies,double, double distance=1mm] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{document}
```