# Tikz, arrow formatting

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

Consider the following picture:
[image]

and the code at the bottom. I'm happy with the result on the left; now I've started with digraphs and I need arrows; I'm trying to get the - for me - best possible style. I would like to achieve the following:

1. The arrow head should have 1pt separation from the bullet, but the tail should have no space and also the normal edges should not, of course
2. [DONE] The head should be like the one in the following post (and not a triangle as in my attempt):  [pgfplots: custom axis arrow head](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141203)
3. [DONE] And the standard head should not appear
4. Since I generate the picture out of python, **the formatting of the arrow should be encapsulated in a style**, as I do for the nodes with the style `bullet`, see my try with `myarrow`

.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49000\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle, fill,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}]\useasboundingbox (-2,-2)rectangle(2,2);\node[bullet] at (2.00000,0.00000) (0) {};
\node[bullet] at (1.00000,1.73205) (1) {};
\node[bullet] at (-1.00000,1.73205) (2) {};
\node[bullet] at (-2.00000,0.00000) (3) {};
\node[bullet] at (-1.00000,-1.73205) (4) {};
\node[bullet] at (1.00000,-1.73205) (5) {};
\draw (0) -- (1); \draw (1) -- (2); \draw (2) -- (3); \draw (3) -- (4); \draw (4) -- (5); \draw (5) -- (0); \end{tikzpicture}\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49000\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[bullet/.style={circle, fill,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}]
[myarrow/.style={-{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm]}}]
\useasboundingbox (-2,-2)rectangle(2,2);\node[bullet] at (2.00000,0.00000) (0) {};
\node[bullet] at (1.00000,1.73205) (1) {};
\node[bullet] at (-1.00000,1.73205) (2) {};
\node[bullet] at (-2.00000,0.00000) (3) {};
\node[bullet] at (-1.00000,-1.73205) (4) {};
\node[bullet] at (1.00000,-1.73205) (5) {};
\draw (0) -- (1); \draw (1) -- (2); \draw (2) -- (3); \draw (3) -- (4); \draw[myarrow] (4) -- (5); \draw[-{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm]}] (5) -- (0); \end{tikzpicture}\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should include `myarrow/.style` inside the first square brackets in order to define the style. In the style you can specify the arrow tip distance from the node with the `sep=1pt` option as in the example below.

If the `myarrow` style is to be used in multiple `tikzpicture` environments, you can define the style in the preamble with `\tikzset{myarrow/.style={...}}` instead of defining it inside the optional arguments to each individual environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{subcaption}

 % Definition of myarrow style to be used in multiple tikzpictures
 % \tikzset{myarrow/.style={-{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm, sep=1pt]}}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49000\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle, fill,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt}]\useasboundingbox (-2,-2)rectangle(2,2);\node[bullet] at (2.00000,0.00000) (0) {};
\node[bullet] at (1.00000,1.73205) (1) {};
\node[bullet] at (-1.00000,1.73205) (2) {};
\node[bullet] at (-2.00000,0.00000) (3) {};
\node[bullet] at (-1.00000,-1.73205) (4) {};
\node[bullet] at (1.00000,-1.73205) (5) {};
\draw (0) -- (1); \draw (1) -- (2); \draw (2) -- (3); \draw (3) -- (4); \draw (4) -- (5); \draw (5) -- (0); \end{tikzpicture}\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49000\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
[bullet/.style={circle, fill,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
 myarrow/.style={-{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm, sep=1pt]}}]
\useasboundingbox (-2,-2)rectangle(2,2);\node[bullet] at (2.00000,0.00000) (0) {};
\node[bullet] at (1.00000,1.73205) (1) {};
\node[bullet] at (-1.00000,1.73205) (2) {};
\node[bullet] at (-2.00000,0.00000) (3) {};
\node[bullet] at (-1.00000,-1.73205) (4) {};
\node[bullet] at (1.00000,-1.73205) (5) {};
\draw (0) -- (1); \draw (1) -- (2); \draw (2) -- (3); \draw (3) -- (4); \draw[myarrow] (4) -- (5); \draw[myarrow] (5) -- (0); \end{tikzpicture}\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Resulting output]

Answer (score 3):

With use `regular polygon` for determining coordinates 
 of bullets (named `dot` in MWE below) and loops for drawing lines in sub figure b. Styles for arrows and nodes' shapes are common for both picture. Arrows are defined by

```
arr/.style = {-{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm]},shorten >=1pt},
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\tikzset{
    dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt},
    arr/.style = {-{Stealth[length=2mm, width=2mm]},shorten >=1pt},
    HEX/.style = {regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6,
                  minimum size=33mm, rotate=-60,
                  node contents={}}
        }
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (n0) [HEX,draw];
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}
\node[dot] at (n0.corner \i) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (n0) [HEX];
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}
\node (n\i) [dot] at (n0.corner \i) {};
\foreach \i [count=\j from 2] in {1,...,4}
    \draw (n0.corner \i) -- (n0.corner \j);
\draw[arr] (n5) -- (n6);
\draw[arr] (n6) -- (n1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use shorten > as an option or in a style.
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,5}
\fill (60*\i:2) circle(2pt) coordinate (A\i); 

\draw (A0)--(A1)--(A2)--(A3)--(A4);
\draw[-stealth, shorten >=3pt] (A4)--(A5);
\draw[-stealth, shorten >=3pt] (A5)--(A0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[myarr/.style={-stealth, shorten >=3pt}]
\foreach \i in {0,...,5}
\fill (60*\i:2) circle(2pt) coordinate (A\i); 

\draw (A0)--(A1)--(A2)--(A3)--(A4);
\draw[myarr] (A4)--(A5);
\draw[myarr] (A5)--(A0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```